# grep - difference between ways of specifying directory and globs

Tags: grep

Say I'm in a project folder and want to grep a keyword using `grep -rni`. What's the difference between these 3 commands?

`grep -rni . -e "keyword"`

`grep -rni * -e "keyword"`

`grep -rni **/* -e "keyword"`

I tested this and noticed that the first two commands return the same number of matches, although in different ordering. The third one returned significantly more matches than the first two, however.

Is there any reason to use the third one ever? Is the reason it's returning more matches duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the difference has nothing to do with the arguments `-n` and `-i`.

From `grep` man page:

```
-n, --line-number
  Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.
```

```
-i, --ignore-case
  Ignore case distinctions in patterns and input data, so that characters that differ only in case match each other.
```

```
-r, --recursive
  Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory.  This is equivalent to the
  -d recurse option.
```

So, the difference is actually on how the strings `*` and `**/*` are interpreted **by the shell**.

With `.` you pass the current directory as an argument to grep. No mystery here because it is grep the one who walks the current working directory.

With `*` you pass every file in the current directory as an argument to grep (this include directories).

Now, suppose you have the following directory structure:

```
├── file.txt
├── one
│   └── file.txt
└── two
    └── file.txt
```

Running `grep -rni * -e keyword` is translated to:

```
grep -rni file.txt one two -e keyword
```

This conditions `grep` to iterate files and nested directories in that order.

Finally, `grep -rni **/* -e keyword` will translate to this command line:

```
grep -rni file.txt one one/file.txt two two/file.txt -e keyword
```

The problem with this last approach is that some files will be processed more than once. For instance: `one/file.txt` will be processed twice: once because it is explicitly in the argument list, and another time because it belongs to the directory `one`, which is also in the argument list.